# Limit of an infinite series with quadratic arguments

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory

I have encountered a limiting process on some infinite series. So, I would like to ask:

> **QUESTION.** Assume $n$ is an even positive integer. Is this true?
> $$\lim_{r\rightarrow1^{-}}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\left(\sqrt{\frac2n}-\cos\left(\frac{\pi j^2}n\right)
> -\sin\left(\frac{\pi j^2}n\right)\right)r^j=\frac12\left(1-\sqrt{\frac2n}\right).$$

Answer (score 3):

We will use the following well known fact (two proofs of this fact can be found at the end of the post):

*Given $f(x)$ with period $1$, its Fourier series
$$
f(x)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j\cos(2\pi jx),
$$
and a positive integer $n\in\mathbb{N}$, one has*
$$
\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_je^{\pi i j^2/n}=\frac{e^{\pi i (1-n)/4}}{\sqrt{n}}\sum _{j=1}^n(-1)^jf\Big(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{j}{n}\Big)e^{-\pi i j^2/n}.
$$

The idea behind this fact might be going back as far as to Dirichlet, though I wasn't able to find an exact reference. Also it is possible that Ramanujan new it, because he studied sums of this kind (see periodic zeta functions in his Lost Notebook).

Now take $a_j=r^j$, $|r|<1$. Then
$$
f(x)=\frac{1-r\cos(2\pi x)}{1-2r\cos(2\pi x)+r^2}.
$$

This allows one to calculate the part of OP's series that contain cosine and sine terms. The part that contains $\sqrt{2/n}$ is trivial.

Now that the series is reduced to a finite sum, one can put $r\to 1-0$.

In the resulting finite sum, the singular terms $(1-r)^{-1}$ come from the terms in the series that contain $\sqrt{2/n}$, and one is contained in the finite sum from $f(0)$ (the term $j=n$), and they would cancel each other.

Since for $x\neq 0$
$$
\lim_{r\to 1}f(x)=1/2,\quad x\neq 0, 
$$
OP's claim reduces to a calculation of a Gauss sum. However, there is no need to calculate this Gauss sum explicitly, because its value follows from the general formula if one takes $f\equiv 1$.

**EDIT**: *1st proof of the general fact* using multisection.
$$
\sum_{j\in\mathbb{Z}} a_je^{\pi i j^2/n}=\sum_{s=1}^ne^{\pi i s^2/n}\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} a_{s+kn}(-1)^k\\
=\sum_{s=1}^ne^{\pi i s^2/n}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^ne^{2\pi isj/n}f(1/2-j/n)\\
=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^nf(1/2-j/n)\sum_{s=1}^ne^{2\pi isj/n}e^{\pi i s^2/n}\\
=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^nf(1/2-j/n)e^{-\pi i j^2/n}\sum_{s=1}^ne^{\pi i (s+j)^2/n}
$$

The inner sum here is a Gauss sum and obviously it does not depend on $j$. Its value is known from other sources. The proof below avoids calculation of Gauss sums, but probably will be called unsatisfiable by some people.

*2nd proof of the general fact* using Poisson summation formula (see transition from the 3rd line to the 4th, where it is effectively applied to a function which is $0$ outside $[-1/2,1/2]$).

\begin{align}
\frac{e^{\pi i/4}}{\sqrt{a}}\sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty a_je^{-\pi i j^2/a}&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) e^{\pi i a x^2}dx\\
&=\int_{-1/2}^{1/2} f(x) \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{\pi i a (x+n)^2}dx\\
&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{\pi i a n}\int_{-1/2}^{1/2} f(x)e^{\pi i a x^2}  e^{2\pi i a n x}dx\\
&=\frac{1}{a}\sum _{n=0}^a f\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{n}{a}\right)e^{\pi i a\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{n}{a}\right)^2}\\
&=\frac{e^{\pi i a/4}}{a}\sum _{n=0}^a (-1)^nf\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{n}{a}\right)e^{\pi i n^2/a}
\end{align}

Comment: Can you explain how the "(well known?) fact" is proved?

Comment: Previous comment continued: Mathematica does not know this identity even for $f=1$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis using periodicity of $e^{\pi i j^2/n}$ and multisection.

Comment: @IosifPinelis you think the general formula is incorrect? I checked it numerically and it works. I don't understand why people don't believe me.

Comment: I think the formula is correct, but the manipulations with the delta functions need detalization/justification. I think answers are written not only for the OP, but also for their other readers -- so, they should be detailed enough in any case.

Comment: @IosifPinelis if you or someone else can give a better answer, why wouldn't you? However, when there is a trivial question pops up, it immediately gets 5 answers, and gets upvoted to the moon.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. No, I don't have a better answer, and I don't think I ever implied anything like that. Concerning the first line of your first proof, I think there is at least one typo there. Concerning the first line of your second proof, I think the factor $(-1)^{-1/4}$ is missing on right-hand side there; hopefully, this does not affect the final result.

Comment: @IosifPinelis thanks, corrected.

Comment: Can you detail the second equality in your first proof (where $f$ first appears) and the use of the Poisson summation formula (?) in your second proof, where $\sum_{n=0}^a$ first appears?

Comment: Also, why the Gauss sums don't depend on $j$? I have just tried $n=5$, and then the sums do depend on $j$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis yes, of course it does, I was sloppy, sorry. The fact that this Gauss sum can not even be simply taken out as a phase factor is good news for Poisson summation, because it shows that the argument with Poisson summation is better: it avoids calculation of a Gauss sum.